# Spring: How to inject a property with a non-setter method?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jetty

Is it possible to inject a property bean through a method with a signature doesn't start with `set`?

Specifically, I'm trying to use Spring to configure an embedded Jetty instance and I need to be able to inject a servlet bean via an `addServlet()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am looking at [Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding Jetty documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty). I guess you mean calling `ServletContextHandler.addServlet()`. You have few choices:

## `@Configuration` (since 3.0)

My favourite approach. You can configure everything using Java!

```
@Configuration
public class Jetty {
    @Bean(initMethod = "start")
    public Server server() {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(context());
        return server;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletContextHandler context() {
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        context.addServlet(servlet(), "/*");
        return context;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletHolder servletHolder() {
        return new ServletHolder(helloServlet());
    }

    @Bean
    public HelloServlet helloServlet() {
        return new HelloServlet();
    }
}
```

## Inheritance/decorating

You can inherit from or wrap original `ServletContextHandler` class to follow Java bean naming conventions. Of course it requires an extra class, but makes Jetty class Spring-friendly. You can even publish such wrapper or maybe someone already did that?

## [`MethodInvokingFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/MethodInvokingFactoryBean.html)

I don't like this approach as it seems too low level. Basically you create a bean that calls arbitrary method with arbitrary arguments:

```
<bean id="javaVersion" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
 <property name="targetObject" ref="servletContextHandler"/>
 <property name="targetMethod" value="addServlet"/>
 <property name="arguments">
   <list>
     <ref bean="yourServlet"/>
   </list>
 </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 3):

just the spring file adapted to Jetty 7. It's possible to add yours contextHandlers...

```
<bean id="contexts"
    class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection" />

<context:property-placeholder location="src/main/resources/ws.properties" />

<!-- Manually start server after setting parent context. (init-method="start") -->
<bean id="jettyServer" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server"
    destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="threadPool">
        <bean id="ThreadPool" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
            <property name="minThreads" value="10" />
            <property name="maxThreads" value="50" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="connectors">
        <list>
            <bean id="Connector" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
                <property name="port" value="8181" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="handler">
        <bean id="handlers" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection">
            <property name="handlers">
                <list>
                    <ref bean="contexts" />
                    <bean id="defaultHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.DefaultHandler" />
                    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler"
                        p:contextPath="/${ws.context.path}">
                        <property name="sessionHandler">
                            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler" />
                        </property>
                        <property name="servletHandler">
                            <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler">
                                <property name="servlets">
                                    <list>
                                        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder"
                                            p:name="spring-ws">
                                            <property name="servlet">
                                                <bean
                                                    class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet" />
                                            </property>
                                            <property name="initParameters">
                                                <map>
                                                    <entry key="contextConfigLocation" value="classpath:/spring-ws-context.xml" />
                                                </map>
                                            </property>
                                        </bean>
                                    </list>
                                </property>
                                <property name="servletMappings">
                                    <list>
                                        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletMapping"
                                            p:servletName="spring-ws" p:pathSpec="/*" />
                                    </list>
                                </property>
                            </bean>
                        </property>
                    </bean>
                    <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler" /> 
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```